# Open up a registry from a remote client

Tags: powershell, batch, windows-registry

I want to make a Script, that ask me for my input (Client) and opens up the registry editor with the client already connected, so I dont have to click manually add network...
Is there a way, in Batch or Powershell, to do this? I dont want directly edit something or search, just the normal GUI Registry Editor (regedit) from the remote client

For Example:
Opens up the cmd

Typing: registry [Client]

Service remote registry from client [Client] has been started

Powershell Script or Batch starts the registry editor from the client

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to be able to map a network drive to their C drive, then you can use `regedit /L:\\pcname\c$\windows\system.dat` to open regedit to that system. See also: https://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/nftechsupt.web+WinBatch/Registry+RegEdit~Command~Line~Options~Syntax.txt

Comment: @LPChip that is not working for me for some reason

Comment: Which registry hive is to be queried? Is it HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Comment: @harrymc not a specific, just the normal GUI Interface from the registry

Comment: See this PowerShell [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34043482/165358). Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Invoke-Command from your workstation to get the registry values you need?

```
Invoke-Command -Computer Server01 {
    Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\run
}
```